# this.setState and following function are not even running

Tags: javascript, reactjs

It's not logging the item of "this.state.UsersAvatars[1]", nor the "check". it's also not changing the array, the only item in UsersAvatars is the first object

Can I please ask for your help? (:

```
  newUserTypeAvatarsArray = async () => {
    const avatars = this.state.avatars.map((avatar, index) => ({
      avatar: avatar,
      isChcecked: false,
      index: index,
    }));
    console.log(avatars);
    let singleUser = {
      userType: "everyone",
      isChecked: false,
      avatars: avatars,
    };
    await this.setState(
      {
        UsersAvatars: [singleUser],
      },
      () => {
        console.log(this.state.UsersAvatars[0]);
      }
    );

    await this.state.users_types.map(async (userTypee, index) => {
      console.log("in loop users_types");
      const temporaryObject = {
        userType: userTypee,
        isChecked: false,
        avatars: avatars,
      };
      let temporaryArray = await [...this.state.UsersAvatars, temporaryObject];
      await this.setState(
        (prevState) => (
          {
            UsersAvatars: temporaryArray,
          },
          function () {
            console.log("check");
            console.log(this.state.UsersAvatars[1]);
          }
        )
      );
    });
    await this.setState({
      UsersAvatarsLoading: false,
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are `await`ing a lot of things, but I don't see a single one that makes sense/where await works as you may think.

For you to be able to `await` something it has to return a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). `async function`s always return Promises.
If you `await something` that is not a Promise or has a `then()`-method this `await` is pointless. `await` does especially not care about functions that use callbacks!

#### 1. `await this.setState(...)`

`await this.setState(...)` is equivalent to calling `this.setState(...)` and `await undefined;`.

Let's fix this quickly and make `setState` awaitable.

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
  setState = (arg, callback=null) => new Promise(
    resolve => super.setState(arg, resolve)
  ).then(callback)
}
```

*For compatibility reasons I left the optional `callback` argument in there, but avoid to use it.*

#### 2. `await this.state.users_types.map(async (userTypee, index) => { ...`

Since you do `array.map(async ...)` you will get an array of promises. But sadly and array of promises is still just an array and not a Promise itself, and therefore you can't `await` it. [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to the rescue.

`await Promise.all(this.state.users_types.map(async (userTypee, index) => { ... })`

#### 3. `let temporaryArray = await [...this.state.UsersAvatars, temporaryObject];`

this is basically an `[].concat(this.state.UsersAvatars, [temporaryObject])`. I don't know why you think you need to `await` that. While Point 2 was at least an array of promises, this is merely an array, without any promises anywhere nereby; or anything asynchronous for that matter. Just get rid of `await` here.

#### 4. [The comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)

`(a, b)` first executes the expression `a` and then executes and *"returns"* expression `b`.

So `var b = (console.log("a is", a), 2*a);` will first log, and `2*a` will be assigned to `var b`.

How is that related to your code? here:

```
this.setState(
  (prevState) => (
    {
      UsersAvatars: temporaryArray,
    },
    function () {
      console.log("check");
      console.log(this.state.UsersAvatars[1]);
    }
  )
);
```

let me rewrite this:

```
this.setState((prevState) => {
    return (
      {
        UsersAvatars: temporaryArray,
      },
      function () {
        console.log("check");
        console.log(this.state.UsersAvatars[1]);
      }
    )
});
```

or

```
this.setState((prevState) => {
  // create an object and ignore it
  ({
    UsersAvatars: temporaryArray,
  });
  // and return the function as "object with changes to the state"
  return function () {
    console.log("check");
    console.log(this.state.UsersAvatars[1]);
  }
});
```

I guess you meant to write

```
this.setState({
    UsersAvatars: temporaryArray
  },
  () => {
    console.log("check");
    console.log(this.state.UsersAvatars[1]);
  }
);
```

---

So much to the obvious errors.

I have a feeling that besides these errors, something is off about what the function does. The fact that `avatars` is an array, and `users_types` is an array and every item in `users_types` contains the entire `avatars` array, and that you call `setState` in a loop, ...

But I have no clue what exactly you're trying to build here and how the code should look like.

---

**Edit:**

@Meir refactored the function from [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66251499/6567275):

```
newUserTypeAvatarsArray = () => {
  const avatars = this.state.avatars.map((avatar, index) => ({ 
    avatar, 
    isChecked: false, 
    index 
  }));
  
  this.setState({
    UsersAvatars: [
      { 
        userType: "everyone", 
        isChecked: false, 
        avatars 
      },
      ...this.state.users_types.map(userType => ({ 
        userType, 
        isChecked: false, 
        avatars 
      }))
    ],
    UsersAvatarsLoading: false,
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the `async/await` pattern on `this.setState`. Even if it is asynchrone, it does not return a promise or something that you can await. It triggers a rerender of your component so I suspect the code following your first `setState` isn't even read.

You seem to know about the callback function of the `setState`, so use it to do your second `setState`. Think about splitting your code in two functions for a better understanding ;)

Here are [some explanation about awaiting setState](https://medium.com/@iamsongcho/is-setstate-async-b1947fbb25e5#:%7E:text=We%20can%20use%20await%20setState,However%2C%20it%20does%20not.)

And here is [a question asking if we can call `setState` in the `setState` callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41544610/using-this-setstate-in-the-callback-of-this-setstate-in-react-js) that you could find interesting.

Comment: Thank you so much you are completely right haha!

Thanks to you I found a really clean way to do this, I'll attach it in a second

Answer (score 0):

```
newUserTypeAvatarsArray = () => {
    const avatars = this.state.avatars.map((avatar, index) => ({
      avatar: avatar,
      isChcecked: false,
      index: index,
    }));
    let singleUser = {
      userType: "everyone",
      isChecked: false,
      avatars: avatars,
    };
    var temporaryUsersAvatarsArray = [singleUser];
    this.state.users_types.map((userTypee, index) => {
      console.log("in loop users_types");
      temporaryUsersAvatarsArray = [
        ...temporaryUsersAvatarsArray,
        {
          userType: userTypee,
          isChecked: false,
          avatars: singleUser.avatars,
        },
      ];
    });
    this.setState({
      UsersAvatars: temporaryUsersAvatarsArray,
      UsersAvatarsLoading: false,
    });
  };
```

This code works :)

Comment: Take a look at the end of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66251506/6567275), I've refactored this a bit.